# Conflicting file usage information - drives filling up

Tags: windows, windows-7, disk-space-utilization, windows-10

Something odd is going on with my VHDXs. The OSs on two of them (Win7 | Win10) are reporting conflicting information regarding disk space usage, with the Win10 file system showing as wildly off (by > 100GB). Disk analysis utilities are reporting the smaller numbers, as does ChkDsk.

Win7 is a clean install, running for about a year now with no usage—it just sits there. It has absolutely nothing installed on it. Win10 runs SQL Server only.

Screen shots are below.

What do you make of it?

---

[image: Win7, Computer report]
[image: Win7, File system report]
[image: Win7, ChkDsk report]
[image: Win10, Computer report]
[image: Win10, File system report]
[image: Win10, ChkDsk report]

Comment: [This may be of interest.](http://serverfault.com/questions/419709/whats-eating-my-drive-space-when-normal-files-hidden-system-doesnt-equal-t)

Comment: @Goatmale: Thanks for the lead. I ran `vssadmin delete shadows /all` and was able to reclaim about 5GB on Win7. `vssadmin list shadows` on Win10 doesn't find anything. So I'm still not much further than before.

Comment: Did you try checking for hidden / system files? On the C:\ drive the WINSXS folder is a killer. The NTFS MFT database, is perhaps large on the the D:\ drive. Page file as well.

Comment: @Goatmale: I'll look at those when I get a chance and get back to you. May be a day or two. Thanks.